# SQL Server 2008 table with multiple Filegroups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, groups

Is this possible? I have never seen it before but recently came into running some servers where the application/service creates a new data file and new data filegroup **every week**. Beyond the absurdity of this design ( and the developer mandate that we keep two years of data on hand, or 104 data files and filegroups) was my question as to "Is this possible?". Many thanks for the education in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called table partitioning.  A single table is created over multiple different filegroups and a column within the table is used to figure out which partition the data for that row should be in.

Comment: I was aware that you could partition databases and files, I was unaware of specific table partitioning. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It was introduced in SQL Server 2005, and requires the Enterprise Edition or higher.